Extending the representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{R})$ to the represention of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})$
Given an finite dimensional complex representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{R})$, I want to extend to a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})$ on the ''same vector space''.
Given $\rho:\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{R})\rightarrow\mathrm{End}(V)$. Since $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})\cong\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{R})\otimes_\mathbf{R}\mathbf{C}$ so for any element $X\in\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C}),X=A\otimes 1+B\otimes i.$
I try to consider $\rho^*:\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})\rightarrow\mathrm{End}(V)$ defined as $\rho(A)+i\rho(B)$. but since $V$ is an $\mathbf{R}$- vector space, so it seems that $\rho(A)+i\rho(B)\notin\mathrm{End}(V).$
So, is there any good choice of $\rho^*$? Thank you!

Do you really mean on the same vector space, or on its complexification ?

you say that you have a complex representation, so $V$ is a complex vector space

As user8268 pointed out, representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ are necessarily complex vector spaces, so you also want to consider a "complex version" of $V$. The easiest and most natural thing to do is to mimic what you did on the level of Lie algebras, i.e. replace $V$ by $V \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ and define $\rho^*$ by $$\rho^*(x \otimes \lambda) := \rho(x) \otimes \lambda$$ for all $x \in \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.
Edit: As is pointed out in the comments to this answer, since $V$ is complex to begin with there is no need to complexify $V$, and in fact your choice of $\rho^*$ is already a homorphism $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \to \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(V)$.

But in OP's setting, $V$ is already a complex vector space, so there is no need to tensor it.

My bad, I was mislead by "but $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space".
